# How to execute a user defined function in SQL that has a paramter being passed to it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

I have a function that I created in SQL, and I need to test to make sure that its functioning properly. I know I can use something like...

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.TestFunction
```

to execute it, but how do I pass a parameter to the function?

Comment: are you passing values from a table column or you are passing values explicitly ??

Comment: @M.Ali, explicit values from my C# code. The ID gets passed via querystring and I use that value as the parameter.

Comment: No thats fine then I was wondering if you were passing the values from a table. In that case you would need to use `CROSS APPLY` but anyway its all good in the hood :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call it with parameter as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.TestFunction (your_parameters_separated_by_commas)
```

If it's one parameter only, you call it as `dbo.TestFunction(@param1)`. If it has multiple parameters, change to `dbo.TestFunction(@param1,@param2...)`.

Comment: So then it should look like this?  SELECT * FROM dbo.TestFunction @SysID? its just the one parameter being passed

Comment: You need the brackets. It's similar to how you would use, say, the inbuilt `CONVERT` function.

Comment: No it would be something like `SELECT * FROM dbo.TestFunction(@SysID)`

Comment: @M.Ali That's what I said, but you are, of course, right.